# Create a zip file on a remote location using PHP SSH2

Tags: php, zip, ssh2-exec

I'm working on a filemanager and my users should be able to download a .zip file from their entire root directory.
I'm using the follow script:

```
$cmd = "";
    if(count($files) > 0) {
        foreach($files as $file) {
            $cmd .= " ". $file['name'];
        }
    }
    $cmd = "cd /home/product$this->_product$path && zip -r $filename.zip$cmd";
    if(ssh2_exec($this->_con, "cd /home/product1/include && zip -r include.zip gl_spawns.inc gl_common.inc")) {
        return $cmd;
    }
```

Anyhow, this script works fine, and it's not much relevant to this problem,
Below you see the cmd that is returned by the script you see above:

```
cd /home/product1/include && zip -r include.zip gl_spawns.inc gl_common.inc
```

When I enter this cmd into my ssh screen using putty, it works perfect.
But when I run this cmd with ssh2_exec in php it only creates a part of the zip file, which is called a random name, and doesn't has a extension, seems like the zip process is canceled for some reason.
This happends everytime.

Anyone knows a way to solve this problem?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

You might have better luck with [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('website.com');
$ssh->login('user', 'pass');

//$ssh->enablePTY();
$ssh->exec('cd /home/product1/include && zip -r include.zip gl_spawns.inc gl_common.inc');
```

If that doesn't work try commenting out the `$ssh->enablePTY()` part.

The reason I mention this is that phpseclib has worked for me in instances where ssh2-exec did not.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but it is to much work to convert all my scripts to phpseclib, may I will, but I think it should also work with ssh2_exec.
I found something that may clear things, when I do not use the CD command, and i only make one command, it works, but then it got the full directory structure of my server inside the zip file, I do not want users to see that.

Comment: You might be able to use https://github.com/phpseclib/libssh2-compatibility-layer to make it so your code uses phpseclib without having to rewrite your code. Like maybe disable libssh2 on the server and try it out with the phpseclib compatibility layer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Neither using ssh2 nor phpseclib did the trick, what solved my issue was calling zip command in silent mode: `zip -uqr container.zip folder` so there wasn't any output

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, it seems ssh2_exec doesn't really handle multiply commands very well, and that is where ssh2_shell comes in, I converted a part of my script to the following code:

```
    $cmds[0] = "cd /home/product$this->_product$path;"; 
    $cmds[1] = "zip -r $filename.zip$cmd;"; 

    $out = ''; 
    $shell=ssh2_shell($this->_con); 

    for($i=0; $i<count($cmds); $i++) { 
        fwrite($shell, $cmds[$i] . PHP_EOL); 
        sleep(1); 
        while($buffer = fgets($shell)) { 
            flush(); 
            $out .= $buffer; 
        } 
    }
```

And it works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$ssh->exec("
  cd home/path/anotherpath/
  zip -rv archive.zip ./*
");
```

Note the linebreaks.

Or this way:

```
$ssh->exec("
  cd home/path/anotherpath/; zip -rv archive.zip ./*
");
```